# How can I hide / show default placeholder with AntDesign React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I'm using Ant Design for inputs in my React project. In the multiple input select, I have the default placeholder message "Select an Option"

```
      {type === 'select' && (
        <Select
          className={isBlack}
          mode="multiple"
          key={inputKey}
          id={inputKey}
          defaultValue={value}
          disabled={isFixed}
        >
          {!isBlack && (
            <Option
              value=""
              selected
              disabled
              hidden
            >
              <span>Select an option</span>

            </Option>
          )}
          {options.map((option, i) => (
            <Option
              className="ant-drop"
              key={`option_${0 + i}`}
              value={option}
            >{option}
            </Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      )}
```

However, after all the options are selected in the dropdown, I can't figure out how to hide the "Select an Option" message after there are no more options to map. At the top level, I tried to use if `value === null` then return the dropdown without data but I think that doesn't make sense because I would be technically rendering the dropdown twice. I'm not sure where to go from here. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I hope i am understanding correctly and without too much context, can't you try the following:

- Display `Select an Option` with more
- Assuming once the user selects an option, you are updating a state or updating something. When you update that state/variable, we can be sure to hide the default option.

So displaying this option will be like this:

```
{(!isBlack && userAnswered) (
        <Option
          value=""
          selected
          disabled
          hidden
        >
          <span>Select an option</span>

        </Option>
)}
```

Where `userAnswered` can be `const userAnswered = !!this.state.dropDownSelectAnswers.length` for example.